# How to create slider(like in the attached photo) in android

Tags: android, user-interface, slider, gallery

I want to create something like this

[image]

I don't want to know how, but I want to know the name of such UI components ( where three views appear with the ability to swipe between them) where the middle appears totally .

Comment: You can use `ViewPager` for that.

Comment: @Chintan Yes, I want to show portion of the right and the left page .. is it possible ?

Comment: isn't your problem solved yet? won't my answer helpful to you?

Answer (score 3):

You should have a look at **[Android Coverflow](http://code.google.com/p/android-coverflow/)**. You can replace default layout with your one.

[image]